# Printing evaluated prompt placeholders to screen

Tags: bash, zsh, prompt, tcsh

Is there a way to print interpreted PS1 variable placeholders to console? Something like

```
$ echo `%u`
```

for printing a username or

```
$ echo `%h`
```

for printing a host. I do know about environment variables I just want to know if there is a way to get same information through `PS1` variable.

Comment: You should say which shell you're using. Especially if it's an uncommon one like tcsh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In zsh, use the `%` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
tmp='%n@%m'; echo ${(%)tmp}
```

In bash, there doesn't seem to be an easy way, but there's a sneaky way:

```
tmp=$(set +x; (PS4='+.\u@\h'; set -x; :) 2>&1); tmp=${tmp#*.}; echo ${tmp%:}
```

In tcsh, I don't think there's a way. (But who uses (t)csh these days anyway?)